# how to update one column of one table from column of another table

Tags: sql

I have a table called UserProductDetails in which UPID is primary key and another table called UserTasks in UPID is just nullable column. Both tables have UserID as common columns.

UPID in UserProductDetails can be multiple for any particular user.

I want to update UserTasks.UPID from any of the UPID from UserProductDetails.

How can I do this?

I am trying somthing as below

```
update UserTasks
set UPID = 
select  MIN(UserProductDetails.UPID) AS UPID, GETDATE() from UserProductDetails where UserId in
(select UserID from UserTasks t) group by UserId
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up using below query based on Milen Pavlov's suggestion

```
/*Adding random but user specific UPID and then making UPID as non-nullable.*/
begin tran
UPDATE
    dbo.UserTasks
SET
    UPID = A.UPID
    FROM
 (SELECT UserId, MIN(CAST(UPID AS BINARY(16))) AS UPID FROM UserProductDetails GROUP BY UserId) A
WHERE userTasks.UserID = A.UserID
COMMIT

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
UPDATE      UserTasks u
SET         u.UPID =  (SELECT MIN(up.UPID)      
                       FROM   UserProductDetails up 
                       WHERE up.UserID = u.UserID)
```

Comment: Thanks Milen... your suggestion was what led me to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to update two columns on the UserTasks table - a date column and the UPID column. If that is the case, the below update should work. It updates the datecolumn to `GETDATE()` and selects one of the UPID values matched to the UserID column on both tables. I have used TOP 1 as you have mentioned any.

```
UPDATE UserTasks
SET 
DateColumn = GETDATE(),
UPID = (SELECT TOP 1 UserProductDetails.UPID
        FROM UserProductDetails
        WHERE UserProductDetails.UserId = UserTasks.UserID)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems in your code.

1. You forgot the braces around your subselect
2. Your subselect must only return one column
3. Restrict the subselect to match the outer query

Try this:

```
update
    UserTasks
set
    UPID = ( 
       select
           min(UserProductDetails.UPID) AS UPID
       from
           UserProductDetails
       where
           UserTasks.UserId = UserProductDetails.UserID
    )
```